# How to drop non-unique index only?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following index in my databases (yes, I have a couple of them).

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "someUniqueField" : 1
    },
    "name" : "someUniqueField_1",
    "ns" : "MyDB.Collection"
}
```

But actually, I wanted to have a unique index. I changed the create index statement for newer databases. But now I have different versions of this index in different databases.

Now I want to delete just thus indexes with unique: false (or with no unique field, displayed in the getIndexes() output).

This commands would drop the index independent of the unique flag.

```
db.collection.dropIndex("someUniqueField_1"); // or
db.collection.dropIndex({"someUniqueField": 1});
```

**Is there something like:**

```
db.collection.dropIndex({"someUniqueField": 1}, {unique: false});
```

I know I could drop all these indices and create a new one, or I could check it manually if the wrong index exists.

But it would be also nice for learning purposes if this is possible.

Comment: Btw: the index name is the same for non-unique indices and for unique indices.

Comment: you can generate list with `db.collection.indexes.find({"unique": false});`

Comment: This command doesn't return any result `db.collection.indexes.find({})`. Even with or without the filter part. But when I run `db.collection.getIndexes()` I found the indexes, but it isn't possible to filter them in an db command. It seems that I have to do it manually.

Comment: sorry - `db.system.indexes.find` instead

Comment: The result is still empty. Maybe this is important: I use the version 3.2.8 of the db. Is this command a new feature? I found your command in many pages, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I found the following: [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/)
<database>.system.indexes
**Deprecated since version 3.0:** Access this data using listIndexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should give you the script?

```
db.a.getIndexes().forEach(function(k) { 
  if (k.key.unique != 1) {
    print("db.a.dropIndex(\"k.name\");");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. It seems that I have to use a script and not just a single command. But it's working.